# Getting RGB Value Live Camera, Error NullPointerException

Tags: java, opencv, android

**[UPDATE]:** Screenshot has been added.

I was following basic tutorial `tutorial-1-camerapreview` from [opencv-3.4.1-android-sdk_4](https://opencv.org/opencv-3-4-1.html).
I want to click on screen and get RGB Color of that `x` `y` position. 
I got help from [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31518499/retrieve-exact-rgb-value-from-touch-event-in-camera-preview) *(Retrieve exact RGB value from touch event in camera preview)*:

**Getting x y coordinates:**

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        x = (int)event.getX();
        y = (int)event.getY();
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
```

**onCameraFrame** as:

```
public Mat onCameraFrame(CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
        mRgba = inputFrame.rgba();
        if(x != -1 && y != -1) { //if this is true, you've touched something
            rgb = mRgba.get(x,y);

            Log.d(TAG, "Touch coordinates--> " + "x: " + String.valueOf(x)
                    + " y: " + String.valueOf(y) + " \n"
                    + "RGB values--> "
                    + " Red: "   + rgb[0]
                    + " Green: " + rgb[1]
                    + " Blue: "  + rgb[2]);


            x = -1;
            y = -1;
        }

        return mRgba;
    }
```

I am getting these errors:

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-904
>
> java.lang.NullPointerException
>
> at test.com.imagecolortest.MainActivity.onCameraFrame(MainActivity.java:104)
>
> at org.opencv.android.CameraBridgeViewBase.deliverAndDrawFrame(CameraBridgeViewBase.java:392)
>
> at org.opencv.android.JavaCameraView$CameraWorker.run(JavaCameraView.java:373)
>
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:838)

**Note:**

Line no. 104 *(MainActivity.java:104)* is:

> - " y: " + String.valueOf(y) + " \n"

**Also**

Sometime it runs as when I click near to Top Left corner of screen it works. But when I click on other places it crashes.

Sometimes when its run by touching *one tap* on screen it gives two logs *(trigger two times)*: (by scanning [this](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-32hGBWeMxJc/TnEK1y8XnFI/AAAAAAAAAUM/AzKULdd6nJc/s1600/Dark_Red_Background.jpg) image with camera)

```
06-22 18:09:24.515 416-806/test.com.imagecolortest D/OCVSample::Activity: Touch coordinates--> x: 340 y: 587 
                                                                             RGB values--> Red: 211.0 Green: 81.0 Blue: 220.0
06-22 18:09:24.613 416-806/test.com.imagecolortest D/OCVSample::Activity: Touch coordinates--> x: 340 y: 587 
                                                                             RGB values--> Red: 205.0 Green: 75.0 Blue: 217.0
```

and sometime when Red `rgb[0]` value is `0` the `Log.d` triggers three times. Don't know why.

**[Edit]:** We can address this issue latter as we are returning `super.onTouchEvent(event)` instead returning `true`. Will add that later.

**My Code:**
**MainActivity.java**

```
package test.com.imagecolortest;

import org.opencv.android.BaseLoaderCallback;
import org.opencv.android.CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame;
import org.opencv.android.LoaderCallbackInterface;
import org.opencv.android.OpenCVLoader;
import org.opencv.core.CvType;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.android.CameraBridgeViewBase;
import org.opencv.android.CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewListener2;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements CvCameraViewListener2 {
    private static final String TAG = "OCVSample::Activity";
    private CameraBridgeViewBase mOpenCvCameraView;
    private boolean              mIsJavaCamera = true;
    private MenuItem mItemSwitchCamera = null;
    private Mat mRgba;
    int x = -1, y = -1;
    double [] rgb;
    TextView touchView;

    private BaseLoaderCallback mLoaderCallback = new BaseLoaderCallback(this) {
        @Override
        public void onManagerConnected(int status) {
            switch (status) {
                case LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS: {
                    Log.i(TAG, "OpenCV loaded successfully");
                    mOpenCvCameraView.enableView();
                } break;
                default: {
                    super.onManagerConnected(status);
                } break;
            }
        }
    };

    public MainActivity() {
        Log.i(TAG, "Instantiated new " + this.getClass());
    }

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.i(TAG, "called onCreate");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mOpenCvCameraView = (CameraBridgeViewBase) findViewById(R.id.activity_main);
        mOpenCvCameraView.setVisibility(SurfaceView.VISIBLE);
        mOpenCvCameraView.setCvCameraViewListener(this);
        touchView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause(){
        super.onPause();
        if (mOpenCvCameraView != null)
            mOpenCvCameraView.disableView();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        if (!OpenCVLoader.initDebug()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Internal OpenCV library not found. Using OpenCV Manager for initialization");
            OpenCVLoader.initAsync(OpenCVLoader.OPENCV_VERSION_3_0_0, this, mLoaderCallback);
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "OpenCV library found inside package. Using it!");
            mLoaderCallback.onManagerConnected(LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS);
        }
    }

    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (mOpenCvCameraView != null)
            mOpenCvCameraView.disableView();
    }

    public void onCameraViewStarted(int width, int height) {
        mRgba = new Mat(height, width, CvType.CV_8UC4);
    }

    public void onCameraViewStopped() {
        mRgba.release();
    }

    public Mat onCameraFrame(CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
        mRgba = inputFrame.rgba();
        if(x != -1 && y != -1) { //if this is true, you've touched something
            rgb = mRgba.get(x,y);

            Log.d(TAG, "Touch coordinates--> " + "x: " + String.valueOf(x)
                    + " y: " + String.valueOf(y) + " \n"
                    + "RGB values--> "
                    + "Red: " + rgb[0]
                    + " Green: " + rgb[1]
                    + " Blue: " + rgb[2]);

// touchView.setText("Touch coordinates--> " + "x: " + String.valueOf(x)
//                    + " y: " + String.valueOf(y) + " \n" + "RGB values--> " + "Red: " + rgb[0]
//                    + " Green: " + rgb[1] + " Blue: " + rgb[2]);
            x = -1;
            y = -1;
        }

        return mRgba;
    }

    //detects touches on screen
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        x = (int)event.getX();
        y = (int)event.getY();

        //Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        //int width = display.getWidth();
        //int height = display.getHeight();
        //double [] rgb = mRgba.get(width,height);


//        touchView.setText("Touch coordinates--> " + "x: " + String.valueOf(x)
//                + " y: " + String.valueOf(y) + " \n" + "RGB values--> " + "Red: " + rgb[0]
//                + " Green: " + rgb[1] + " Blue: " + rgb[2]);

        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:opencv="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <org.opencv.android.JavaCameraView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:id="@+id/activity_main"
        opencv:show_fps="true"
        opencv:camera_id="any" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_gravity="left|bottom" />


</FrameLayout>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="test.com.imagecolortest">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="false"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.front" android:required="false"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.front.autofocus" android:required="false"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        >
        <activity   android:name=".MainActivity"
                    android:screenOrientation="landscape"
                    android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
    <supports-screens android:resizeable="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:anyDensity="true" />

</manifest>
```

**[UPDATE]**

I think I am not defining boundaries *(width, height, pixels etc)* to `click event`. As when I click on *left side of screen* it works, but when I click on other corners/sides *(very far from center)* the app crashes. 
I am displaying live data on screen with

```
Imgproc.putText() as: Imgproc.putText(mRgba,"R:"+rgb[0] + " G:"+rgb[1] +" B:"+rgb[2] + "x: " + x + " y: " + y, new Point(10,52), Core.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX,.7, new Scalar(5,255,255),2,8,false );
```

and I have noted some very strange behavior. The `y` (vertical) value is okay. But when I am sliding my finger from left to right the `x` value works good at range of `0-599`, when it touches value of `600` suddenly app crashes.
Please see attached below photo:
[image: Screenshot]

> 14.93 FPS@800x600
>   R:134.0 G:155.0 B:151.0
>   x: 371 y: 488

- The Red dot shows, where my finger is right now.
- The Red Rectangle *(actually square)* shows that when I touching inside this, my app works but when it goes beyond *(to very right)* it crashes.

Comment: Why do you need `String.valueOf`? Just add `x` and `y` directly to the string

Comment: I suspect `inputFrame.rgba()` is null or `inputFrame == null`. Can you check both?

Comment: Hi @cricket_007 `if (inputFrame == null)` Android Studio gives me this warning: `Condition 'inputFrame == null' is always 'false'`. In my case `if (inputFrame.rgba() == null)` gives me `false`, `not null`. And by doing: `if (null != y)` AndroidStudio v2.1.2 gives this error`Operator '!=' cannot be applied to 'null', 'int'`. cc: @Khanal, I do not think `x` & `y` is null or having some problem. I can `Log.d(TAG, "x: " + x + " y: " + y);` by touching anywhere on screen. I just comment down those: `rgb[0], rgb[1], rgb[2]` Seems like there is some problem with: `rgb = mRgba.get(x, y);`

Comment: I have again this feeling that I am not defining my screen size to app. I am using Huawei Honor h30-u10 and when I open my above app in it, I just have some portion of camera preview on my screen and I have black bar at left and right side of my screen (landscape). This forced to think me the camera visible on my screen is having `x` i-e: width equal to `600`. I may be wrong.  But also when I click on Top-left corner of black screen (right below my front camera) I can get value of `x` and `y`. I believe this is positive finding.

Answer (score -1):

CvCameraViewFrame.rgba() returns a Mat, and OpenCV Mat indexing takes row first, then column.  You're calling `rgb = mRgba.get(x,y);` so you're passing x as the row and y as the column, which will be out of bounds for an 800x600 display when x >= 600.

https://docs.opencv.org/java/2.4.9/org/opencv/core/Mat.html#get(int,%20int)).

Comment: Thank You very much for answer, I will check and get back soon. @Chungzuwalla got one question. If my screen is in `Landscape` mode (as in picture and I forced it in Manifest as: `android:screenOrientation="landscape"`) so in that case my `x` is `row` and `y` is `column`, my attached picture shows `rows` pixels are: `800`. So why am I getting error? My `x` is `800`. Am I right?

Comment: I don't know about Android development, only OpenCV. So I don't know what effect the screen orientation has on your code. However, display resolutions are normally expressed as WIDTHxHEIGHT (eg. 1920x1080 for HD, never 1080x1920) and the order x,y is commonly used in 2D graphics, whereas matrix dimensions are normally written as ROWS×COLS and are indexed with the row first (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_(mathematics)). Switching between the two notations at appropriate places in your code is part of programming a graphics system that uses OpenCV.

Comment: In C++, one way to avoid this error is to always index a cv::Mat with a cv::Point, because the Point constructor takes the usual 2D graphics order (x,y): `uchar val = mat.at<uchar>(cv::Point(x,y));`

Comment: Hello I changed `public void onCameraViewStarted(int width, int height) {mRgba = new Mat(height, width, CvType.CV_8UC4);}` to `public void onCameraViewStarted(int width, int height) {mRgba = new Mat(width, height, CvType.CV_8UC4);}` So this made vertical `y` perfect but `x` not going beyond `599`. Also changed sequence of `x` and `y` in `rgb=mRgba.get(x, y);` but it didn't worked.

Comment: Also by doing: `Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); int width2 = display.getWidth(); int height2 = display.getHeight();` I am getting `1280 x 720` and by `Log.d-ing` valu of `width` and `height` from: `mRgba = new Mat(width, height, CvType.CV_8UC4);` I get: `800x600` which is perfect. cc: @ Chungzuwalla

Comment: Hello, if my screen is `1280 x 720` and my camera resolution is `800x600`, it is obvious that it would trigger _NPException_. Anyway to work this out? Anyone please? Do I need this ([Android + OpenCV: How to set camera resolution when using CameraBridgeViewBase](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17872107/5737774))